# How does __eq__ work against node1.x == node2.x and node 1.y == node2.y?

Tags: python, equals

I have a node class which has x and y attributes. I am trying to optimise my code but my **eq** method takes most of the time. 
Is node1.x == node2.x and node1.y == node2.y the same as using **eq** method ?

Comment: This sounds a lot like you're using `in` with lists, or doing something else that requires way too many `==` comparisons.

Comment: As for how `__eq__` works, that depends entirely on how you implemented `__eq__`, which we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

eq(a, b) is equivalent to a == b

look here https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: That's `operator.eq`, which isn't quite the same thing as the `__eq__` method the questioner attempted to refer to. (`__eq__` becomes __eq__ in Markdown if you don't code-format it.)